# Facebook Messenger API For Composing / Receiving Messages as a Business

Tags: facebook

Does Facebook offer any APIs for sending and receiving Messenger messages outside of Facebook? For example, is it possible to write a calculator app (server receives message from Facebook and executes calculation then messages back user) or a weather app (every day the server messages a user the current weather)?

From researching it seems like these features may be possible under the [Messenger for Business](https://www.messenger.com/business) but the APIs might not be generally accessible.